# How to aggregate state log data into time intervals with the same state in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a log of object states that looks like this

```
timestamp, object_id, state, level
2018-01-01 123        f      100 
2018-01-02 123        t      100    
2018-01-02 123        f      100
2018-01-03 123        f      100
2018-01-03 123        f      100
2018-01-06 123        t      90
2018-01-07 123        t      90
2018-01-08 123        f      90
```

The timestamp is actually a full date/time, I didn't include time component for brevity.

What I want to get is a list of state transitions based on unique state and level that looks like this

```
start      end        object_id, state, level
2018-01-01 2018-01-02 123        f      100 
2018-01-02 2018-01-02 123        t      100
2018-01-02 2018-01-06 123        f      100
2018-01-06 2018-01-08 123        t      90
2018-01-08 NOW()      123        f      90
```

I tried to come up with a way to do this using window functions, something like

```
SELECT
    timestamp,
    object_id,
    timestamp as start,
    lead(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) as end,
FROM (
    SELECT
        timestamp,
        object_id,
        state,
        evel,
        rank() OVER (PARTITION BY (state, level) ORDER BY timestamp) as rank
    FROM state_log AS l
    WHERE object_id=123 AND timestamp >= DATE '2018-01-01'
    ORDER BY timestamp
) AS states
WHERE rank=1
```

But I think I do not understand how rank() works and it does not do what I need. For some reason I thought rank() would reset row counts every time partition changes, but it does not. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Does your timestamp have a time component?  If not, the ordering is unstable, which makes your problem impossible to solve (unless another column specifies the ordering).

Comment: Yes, it does, it is a full time stamp. Didn't include it because it made my post too bulky.

Comment: Edited the post to include this information

Comment: I am not sure about requirements but probably it helps you to start: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3b491a472c0183d26364ff992bda8156

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  A nice solution uses `row_number()`:

```
select object_id, level, state, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by object_id, level order by timestamp) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by object_id, level, state order by timestamp) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by (seqnum - seqnum_2), object_id, level, state;
```

It is a little difficult to explain why this works.  But if you look at the results of the subquery, you will see that the difference between the two `seqnum`s is constant when the state is constant.  That defines the grouping that you want -- along with the other columns -- so the rest is just aggregation.

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/IJPSH74649) showing it working.

Comment: Lemme try it out on my data

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately. Returns results, but after the first row, min and max report the same timestamp

Comment: But thank you for the "gaps and islands" name, at least now I know what to google :)

Comment: @MadWombat . . . It works fine when I try it on the sample data you have in your question.  The last row is a little different -- I'm not quite sure how the second date becomes "now()", but that seems pretty minor.

Comment: That is sample data. Real data has multiple object ids and many different state+level combinations. When I wrote now() in the expected result, I meant that if there is no next state for the object, assume that it is still in its last state and set the end of the last interval to the current time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not about "gaps and islands". This technique operates by groups with consequentive constant values of some field but you need to operate with bounds of such groups. So:

```
create table state_log(timestamp timestamp, object_id int, state boolean, level int);
insert into state_log values
  ('2018-01-01 00:00:01', 123, 'f', 100),
  ('2018-01-02 00:00:02', 123, 't', 100),
  ('2018-01-02 00:00:03', 123, 'f', 100),
  ('2018-01-03 00:00:04', 123, 'f', 100),
  ('2018-01-03 00:00:05', 123, 'f', 100),
  ('2018-01-06 00:00:06', 123, 't', 90),
  ('2018-01-07 00:00:07', 123, 't', 90),
  ('2018-01-08 00:00:08', 123, 'f', 90);

select
  timestamp::date as start,
  coalesce(lead(timestamp) over (order by timestamp), now()::timestamp)::date as end,
  object_id, state, level
from (
  select 
    *,
    coalesce(lag(state) over (order by timestamp) <> state, true) as is_new_group
  from state_log) as t
where
  object_id = 123 and timestamp >= date '2018-01-01' and
  is_new_group
order by timestamp;
```

Result (I remove time part to make it more like to the result you are specified in the question):

```
┌────────────┬────────────┬───────────┬───────┬───────┐
│   start    │    end     │ object_id │ state │ level │
├────────────┼────────────┼───────────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 2018-01-01 │ 2018-01-02 │       123 │ f     │   100 │
│ 2018-01-02 │ 2018-01-02 │       123 │ t     │   100 │
│ 2018-01-02 │ 2018-01-06 │       123 │ f     │   100 │
│ 2018-01-06 │ 2018-01-08 │       123 │ t     │    90 │
│ 2018-01-08 │ 2018-08-30 │       123 │ f     │    90 │
└────────────┴────────────┴───────────┴───────┴───────┘
```